# Change %ds segment in ld

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

By default, `ld` assumes that the `%ds` segment contains 0. So it links my C bootloader-like program using this value and corresponding offset values. Is it possible to change this value in linker settings, so when I set `%ds` in my program to, say, 0x07c0 (as it is done in some tutorials) the program will work correctly? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: %ds segment?  which segment is that?  please post the linker command file and 'c' code that is trying to change that value.   Suggest editing question to indicate which OS, which architecture/CPU